# Changing a Wolf's health after summoning it does not work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

First I do this:

```
/summon Wolf 183 81 196 {Angry:1,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:6},{Name:"generic.followRange",Base:42},{Name:"generic.attackDamage",Base:3}],DropChances:[0.1F,0.75F,0.5F,0.25F,0.11F],Equipment:[{id:"minecraft:tripwire_hook",tag:{display:{Name:"Stage 1"}},Count:1},{id:"minecraft:gold_nugget",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:gold_nugget",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:gold_nugget",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:gold_nugget",Count:1}]}
```

Then I do this:

```
/summon Wolf 183 81 196 {Angry:1,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:13},{Name:"generic.followRange",Base:42},{Name:"generic.attackDamage",Base:3}],DropChances:[0.1F,0.75F,0.5F,0.25F,0.11F],Equipment:[{id:"minecraft:tripwire_hook",tag:{display:{Name:"Stage 3”}},Count:1},{id:"minecraft:gold_nugget",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:gold_nugget",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:gold_nugget",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:gold_nugget",Count:1}]}
```

The first one works but not the second. The second one returns this:

> [04:40:38] Data tag parsing failed: Unbalanced quotation

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem:

`{display:{Name:"Stage 3”}}`

If you look at the second quotation mark, it doesn't quite look the same as the first one. Since it's a different character, the quotation is not balanced.

Here is how it should be:

`{display:{Name:"Stage 3"}}`